# Error when using Ternary if...else operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I am trying to start using shorthand javascript in my code and I am not very adept at it yet. I was trying to convert my `if...else` statements to `ternary if...else`. I am getting an error when I try.

Javascript:

```
if (x.includes(name)) {
  metric_val = funcOne(a);
} else if (y.includes(name)) {
  metric_val = funcTwo(a);
}
```

Ternary if...else

```
let metric_val = (x.includes(name)) ? funcOne(a) : (y.includes(name)) ? funcTwo(a);
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: every ternary need to have `?` and `:`

Comment: Your last ternary has no 'else' part

Comment: Don't use ternary operators like this. This reduces the readability of code too much.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `(y.includes(name))` is the else if part. I dont have an `else` just in case I might need to add another condition later

Comment: @noob that's in the else part of the first ternary. The second one is missing it, ie. after `funcTwo(a)`

Comment: Can you please tell that should be `metric_val` if both the conditions are false?

Comment: I almost feel bad writing this, but here is an alt. `const metric_val = (x.includes(name) && funcOne || y.includes(name) && funcTwo)(a)` however just use the `if/else` statement.

Comment: note: that will fail if the name is in neither list, however it appears you expect it to be in at least one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There mustn't be other `?` after `:`, so the correct way is to use brackets correctly

```
metric_val = x.includes(name) ? funcOne(a) : (y.includes(name) ? funcTwo(a) : null);
```

There will be `null` if both are `false`

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary (though it's fairly harmless to include them for emphasis). The important thing is to supply values to use both for true and false conditions for *both* conditional operators. (You've used `null` for the "they're both false," but it would fit the original `if`/`else if` better to use `metric_val`.)

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely correct, but I have a convention to use brackets, so no typos etc :) And also, yes there should be `metric_val` if both false, but from his ternary it looks like he is setting it there, so it would be `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Your `if`/`else if` doesn't assign to `metric_val` when neither condition matches. You need something to assign to it in that case if you're going to do nested conditional operators (which I wouldn't). That's the problem, you haven't supplied the "neither matches" value.

Presumably, you want the "neither matches" value to be `metric_val`, so it behaves like your `if`/`else if` (essentially):

```
metric_val = x.includes(name) ? funcOne(a) : y.includes(name) ? funcTwo(a) : metric_val;
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(You don't need parentheses in that expression unless you want them for emphasis.)

Answer (score 0):

The code throws error because you need to have an expression in each ternary operator if the value is `false`. You can use `null` for that.

```
let metric_val = (x.includes(name)) ? funcOne(a) : (y.includes(name)) ? funcTwo(a) : null;
```

But this not a good way at all to handle this problem. If you have 2 values then `if-else` is fine. Otherwise create an array object and then loop through it to assign the correct value.

```
const arr = [
    [x, funcOne],
    [y, funcTwo]
    ...
]
let found = arr.find(([arr]) => arr.includes(name))
if(found){
   metric_val = found[1](a)
}
```